# Is the transit area of Ataturk/Istanbul airport open early in the morning?

Tags: transit, airports, isl

I will have about 7 hours transit at Istanbul Ataturk and my first flight will arrive there at 04:45 am. Will the transit be open at this time ? In other words, can I directly go to transit or should I wait outside the transit until it will be opened ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Istanbul Ataturk airport is open 24 hours. I have personally gone through transfer in the international zone at 4 or 5 in the morning several times. I believe the domestic zone is the same. Note that the gate information likely won't be available until about two hours before departure of your second flight.

Please edit your question and add details of your flights (from/to locations, times, airlines, whether they are all on one ticket or separate tickets) - and we might be able to help further.

Comment: I will have two international flights, all with turkish airlines and on one ticket

Comment: @yaya Are they domestic or international? What cities?

Comment: @AleksG Why are you asking if their international flights are domestic or international? How is it relevant what cities they're flying between?

Comment: @DavidRicherby The OP doesn't say whether they are flying domestic or international, but that may make a difference in conditions.

Comment: @AleksG It's right there in the comment you're replying to: "I will have two **international flights**" (emphasis mine)